# Writing css classes in java files

Tags: java, css, jsdt

I need to format a static bit of headings that were coded within a java file as follows

```
public String getShortDescription() {

        if (code != null) {
            if (isOption1()) {
                return "Option 1 heading";          
            } else if (isOption2()) {
                return "Option2 heading";   
            } else if (isOption3()) {
                return "Option3 heading";   
            } else {
                return "";
            }
        } else {
            return "";
        }
    }
```

Is there a quick way to add css classes to the heading part i.e return "`Option <span class="heading">1 heading</span>"` ?

Comment: I would rethink this - bad idea.

Comment: I agree and understand why you are saying this. I just ask if there was a way to quickly achieve this without the need to re code this existing java file because I am not a java developer.

Comment: If you must, create a custom class that includes the description and CSS class and return that instead of String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it's bad to mix your data and display markup within your Java code. However, if there is no other workaround, then you could do the following:

```
public static String wrapText(String text, String cssClass) {
    if (text == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Text to wrap is null");
    }
    if (cssClass == null) {
        cssClass = "";
    }
    return "<span class=\"" + cssClass + "\">" + text + "</span>";
}

public String getShortDescription() {
    if (isOption1()) {
        return "Option " + wrapText("1 heading","heading");
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I have applied the above but it just spits out the html, doesn't apply the formatting

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't apply the formatting"? The Java method should be returning html with the included <span> and css class. If you need to apply styles to the "heading" class, you will need a separate stylesheet in your html document.

Comment: What I mean is, the browser renders Option <span class="heading">Heading 1</span>. I already have css specified for the class="heading"

Comment: My best guess is that some other code is escaping the html content. That's the only reason I can think why your browser wouldn't be rendering the html content. You could view source to see if the < and > tags are being replaced by &lt; and &gt;.

Comment: I have used this escapeXml="false" and it worked. Great, thanks!